# Accessing directive scope from a separate controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Let's say i have a `<lightbox>` directive in AngularJS. The lighbox has two params: `title` and `image_source`, which in turn are referenced in its HTML with `{{title}}` and `{{image_source}}`.

Because I use **Bootstrap**'s modal, the directive must say on the outmost scope of the page (if I insert it in the inner DOM elements it can have display problems).

I understand that if the directive is in a "parent" controller, there are many ways to interact:

```
<div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
  <lightbox src='mySrc' ... >
</div>
```

but I am forced to pull it out:

```
<div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
</div>
<lightbox ...>
```

(**Edit**: to clarify: i am **forced** to put the modal OUT of the controller (which is a template called by a route) because it interacts badly if it is not. Another way would be to wrap all the page in a Main controller, but I'm not sure it's elegant.)

But how do I access the internal directive scope and change dynamically the two values?

(Edit: thought of using a service, not sure if it is the right way, though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is method to call rootscope to directive

```
angular.module("directiveAPP", [])
    .controller("directiveController", function ($scope, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.src = "http://picbook.in/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/image_123.jpg";
    $rootScope.title = "hai";
}).directive("lightBox", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div><img src="{{imageSrc}}" title="{{imageTitle}}" width="100px" style="border:solid #ddd 1px;" /></div>',
        scope: {
            imageSrc: '=',
            imageTitle: '='
        }
    };
});
```

this one use of directive

```
<div ng-app="directiveAPP">
    <div ng-controller="directiveController">
        <light-box image-src="src" image-title="title"></light-box>
    </div>
    <light-box image-src="src" image-title="title"></light-box>
</div>
```

[***FIDDLE LINK***](http://jsfiddle.net/RajamohanShilpa/cj8me083/1/)

Comment: Thanks but this is *not* what I was asking for. Directive and controller are *separate*. In other words, there is no parent scope and I must control the parameters from a *non*-parent scope.

Comment: Edited my post to clarify.

Comment: you ask about with out any controller to use that directive? or if any other scope is their

Comment: yep, the problem is that the HTML generated must be direct child of <body> tag to work properly. I could wrap all the page ina big main controller, or use $rootScope, but I'm not sure it's the right way to do it...

Comment: You getting src and title values from the $rootscope to use it in directive. am i correct?

Comment: Okay just check that above edited code that one is with out use of parent property. i think that may be that will help you. i am not sure about you expectation is over. please check that one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60696/discussion-between-rajashilpa-and-cranio).

Comment: Don't worry, checked the updated fiddle. It seems like $rootScope can be a way to go, thanks for the help :)